# My take on the algorithmic crush problem from HackerRank

Tags: python, performance, programming-challenge

This is my solution to the [Algorithmic Crush](https://www.hackerrank.com/contests/w4/challenges/crush) problem from HackerRank. Can I get any comments regarding where I can improve the code to be more efficient?

> You are given a list of size \$N\$, initialized with zeroes. You have
>   to perform \$M\$ operations on the list and output the maximum of
>   final values of all the \$N\$ elements in the list. For every
>   operation, you are given three integers \$a, b\$ and \$k\$ and you
>   have to add value to all the elements ranging from index \$a\$ to
>   \$b\$ (both inclusive).
>
> **Input Format**
>
> First line will contain two integers \$N\$ and \$M\$ separated by a
>   single space. Next \$M\$ lines will contain three integers \$a, b\$
>   and \$k\$ separated by a single space. Numbers in list are numbered
>   from \$1\$ to \$N\$.
>
> **Constraints**
>
> \$3 \leq N \leq 10^7\$
>
> \$1\leq M \leq 2*10^5\$
>
> \$1 \leq a \leq b \leq N\$
>
> \$ 0 \leq k \leq 10^9\$
>
> **Output Format**
>
> A single line containing *maximum value in the updated list*.
>
> **Sample Input**
>
> ```
> 5 3
> 1 2 100
> 2 5 100
> 3 4 100
> ```
>
> **Sample Output**
>
> ```
> 200
> ```

```
def updateList(seq, listA):
    st, end, value = map(int, seq.split())
    for i in range(st-1, end):
        listA[i] = listA[i]+value
    return listA

n, m = map(int, raw_input().split())

lis = [0 for i in range(n)]

for ins in range(m):
    cmds = raw_input()
    resultSet = updateList(cmds, lis)
    lis = resultSet
print sorted(resultSet)[-1]
```

Comment: I think the biggest improvement (to _the question_, not to the code) would be adding a problem statement.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The code is generally clean, however, maintaining the same algorithm will probably result in a timeout for this problem. Your current complexity is \$ O(N\cdot M) \$ which could be up to \$ 10^7 \times 10^5 \$ according to the problem statement.

A similar problem to this is the maximum interval overlap problem, discussed [here](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/find-the-point-where-maximum-intervals-overlap/). The problem is given the guest arrival and departure times in a party, find the interval with the maximum guests. It should be a good exercise to apply the same idea to this problem.

Comment: It's basically a 1D collision detection. The article you link uses sweep and prune to solve it. It is a very good read but if one needs further reading: There are a lot of articles on sweep and prune on the web.